# Stuck transforming an Object structure

Tags: javascript

Given an object in the form:

```js
{
  attributeA: ['valA1', 'valA2'],
  attributeB: ['valB1'],
  attributeC: ['valC1', 'valC2', 'valC3'],
}
```

I would like to transform it to:

```js
{
  attributeA: false,
  valA1: false,
  valA2: false,
  attributeB: false,
  valB1: false,
  attributeC: false,
  valC1: false,
  valC2: false,
  valC3: false,
}
```

I'm not versatile using the `reduce` method but I got as far as this:

```js
Object.entries(attributes).reduce((p, c) => {
   return [].concat(p, c[0], c[1]);
}, []);
```

Which returns an array of all elements and its values like:

```js
[attributeA, valA1, valA2, attributeB, valB1, attributeC, valC1, valC2, valC3]
```

I'm having a hard time to properly define my reduce function to return the output I need

Comment: While you *can* do it with `reduce` (because any array operation can be shoehorned into a call to `reduce`), there's no point over just using loops. If you're not doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions, `reduce` is just an overcomplicated loop.

Comment: It is indeed, I just can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep it simple and use loops:

```
const result = {};
for (const [name, array] of Object.entries(original)) {
    result[name] = false; // attributeA, etc.
    for (const value of array) {
        result[value] = false;
    }
}
```

```js
const original = {
    attributeA: ["valA1", "valA2"],
    attributeB: ["valB1"],
    attributeC: ["valC1", "valC2", "valC3"],
};

const result = {};
for (const [name, array] of Object.entries(original)) {
    result[name] = false; // attributeA, etc.
    for (const value of array) {
        result[value] = false;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

...but it *is* possible to do it with a combination of `Object.fromEntries`, `Object.entries`, and `flatMap`:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(original).flatMap(([key, array]) => [[key, false], ...array.map(value => [value, false])])
);
```

```js
const original = {
    attributeA: ["valA1", "valA2"],
    attributeB: ["valB1"],
    attributeC: ["valC1", "valC2", "valC3"],
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(original).flatMap(([key, array]) => [[key, false], ...array.map(value => [value, false])])
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is wrong of using `reduce()`? it's also a loop and saves the use of the `result` variable.

Comment: @zb22 - You're going to store the result somewhere, though, right? :-) But use it if you like! (And if your team is okay with it.) For me, it's over-complicated, hard to read, and easy to get wrong (like forgetting to return the accumulator, or missing out an initial value and having it work until it blows up when you pass it an empty array). So I ([and](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) [others](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224)) have come to the view that it's best left only to its original use case: FP with predefined, reusable reducers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Object
const obj = {
  attributeA: ['valA1', 'valA2'],
  attributeB: ['valB1'],
  attributeC: ['valC1', 'valC2', 'valC3'],
};

// Define new object
let newObj = {};

// Simple loop of object
for(const el in obj) {
  // Put element name in new object
  newObj[el] = false;
  // Loop through el value and add them to
  // new object
  for(const item of obj[el]) newObj[item] = false;
}

// Test
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to make the object, 
Inside each iteration, create the `key` and iterate the `value` which is an array with `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```js
const obj = {
  attributeA: ['valA1', 'valA2'],
  attributeB: ['valB1'],
  attributeC: ['valC1', 'valC2', 'valC3'],
}

const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = false;
  value.forEach(item => acc[item] = false);

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```